# One to Many Mapping relationship is not saving data correctly

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, arraylist, one-to-many

I am searching for a long time for accessing my data and post it into my database.
I got succeed to send the name of my report but not the chapter who are linked to.I have Audits to Chapters mapped in one to many relations.Thanks for help, I hope i'm enought clear ^^", I'm french and novice in development.
My database: [image: Database]
There is my request json for spring boot:

```
{
    "nameReport": "Title of the report",
    "chapters": [
        {
            "titleChap": "Title of the chapter",
            "descChap": "The description of the chapter"
        },
            "titleChap": "2nd Title of the chapter",
            "descChap": "2nd description of the chapter"
        }
    ]
}
```

Audit.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="audits")

public class Audit {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "report_name")
  private String nameReport;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="audit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Collection<Chapter> chapters;

  public Audit() {
  }

  public Audit(String nameReport, Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
    this.chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    this.nameReport = nameReport;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getNameReport() {
    return nameReport;
  }

  public void setNameReport(String nameReport) {
    this.nameReport = nameReport;
  }

  public Collection<Chapter> getChapters() {
    return chapters;
  }

  public void setChapters(Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
    this.chapters = chapters;
  }
```

Chapter.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="chapitres")

@Component
public class Chapter {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
//  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "audit_id")
  private Audit audit;

  @Column(name = "chapter_title")
  private String titleChap;

  @Column(name = "chapter_desc")
  private String descChap;

  public Chapter() {}

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Audit getAudit() {
    return audit;
  }

  public void setAudit(Audit audit) {
    this.audit = audit;
  }

  public String getTitleChap() {
    return titleChap;
  }

  public void setTitleChap(String titleChap) {
    this.titleChap = titleChap;
  }

  public String getDescChap() {
    return descChap;
  }

  public void setDescChap(String descChap) {
    this.descChap = descChap;
  }
```

auditController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")

public class AuditController {
  private AuditRepository auditRepository;

  @Autowired
  AuditController(AuditRepository auditRepository){
    this.auditRepository = auditRepository;
  }

  @PostMapping("/audits")
  public ResponseEntity<Audit> postAudit(@RequestBody Audit audit, @RequestBody Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
    try {
      Audit _audit = auditRepository.save(new Audit(audit.getNameReport(), audit.getChapters()));
      return new ResponseEntity<>(_audit, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
  }

  @GetMapping("/audits")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Audit>> getAllAudits() {
    List<Audit> audits = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      auditRepository.findAll().forEach(audits::add);

      if(audits.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(audits, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
      }
      return new ResponseEntity<>(audits, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }

  @GetMapping("/audits/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Audit> getAuditById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Optional<Audit> auditData =  auditRepository.findById(id);

    if (auditData.isPresent()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(auditData.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Aymeric , I understood the problem partially , Please let me know if am i wrong , you want to say that in one to many relationship between Audit and Chapter , you are able to save Audit properly but Chapters are not getting stored .

Comment: Also Can you please add your database schema and the exception you are getting so that problem would be more clear

Comment: Yes I'm able to save my Audit, but not chapters.
Yeah I'm do it now. Thanks !

Comment: I added my database, but I havent exception ! @MandarDharurkar

Comment: Thanks for edit my question  @MandarDharurkar

Comment: I already check on it, I use this code to mine ahah  . But thank you (I check again so ) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution

```
public Audit(String nameReport, Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
    this.chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    this.nameReport = nameReport;
  }
```

You are creating new arraylist here hence chapters are not getting added in Audit . You should change this to

> ```
>  public Audit(String nameReport, Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
>         this.chapters =chapters;
>         this.nameReport = nameReport;
>       }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! 
Now I get an exception on springboot console: ```Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed]```

Comment: @Aymeric it is because you are using 2 requestbody in postAudit method in controller , which is not allowed   . More details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222014/7029988

Comment: Ok , I need to read it srsly.
I get an error and I alredy fall on it ... Idk how to manage this exception.
```The field 'audit_id' can't be empty (null)```

Comment: Hey @Aymeric , it would be better if you accept the answer and close this issue :) .you can create new question with the issue that you are getting .I am happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

```
public Audit(String nameReport, Collection<Chapter> chapters) {
    this.chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    this.nameReport = nameReport;
}
```

You are creating empty list of chapters.

Comment: Thanks @Minh Trí Nguyễn